# AppleScript clipboard isn't being properly set each time the script is run

Tags: applescript, emoji

I have an AppleScript I am running that saves the current clipboard to a temporary variable, sets the clipboard to something else (in this case an emoji), pastes the clipboard into a field, and then reverts the clipboard to what it was before the script was run.

```
set temp to the clipboard
set the clipboard to ""
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "v" using command down
end tell
set the clipboard to temp
```

It works correctly when it is first run but if its run two or more times, it'll paste the emoji the first time followed by the original clipboard every other time after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue on my end by just adding a delay...

```
set temp to the clipboard
set the clipboard to ""
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "v" using command down
    delay 0.3
end tell
set the clipboard to temp
```